# ReactNative fails to deploy build to iOS simulator but does deploy it to Android emulator

Tags: react-native, cfbundleidentifier

ReactNative fails to deploy build to iOS simulator but does deploy it to Android emulator

Attached are screenshots showing this on both.

Steps:

1. Created react native app

   react-native init proto
2. Run app on Android emulator after I started emulator

   react-native run-android

this is running fine on Android emulator

3. Run app on iOS simmulator

   react-native run-ios

This produces error as per screenshot

**Error**

```
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    CompileC /Users/dinob/reactnativework/proto/ios/build/Build/Intermediates/React.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/React.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/RCTShadowView+Internal.o Views/RCTShadowView+Internal.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)

Installing build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/proto.app
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=2):
Failed to install the requested application
An application bundle was not found at the provided path.
Provide a valid path to the desired application bundle.
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

Command failed: /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Print:CFBundleIdentifier build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/proto.app/Info.plist
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist
```

**Versions**

```
MacBookPro OSX El Capitain

react-native 0.55.3

react-native-cli 2.0.1

npm 5.5.1

node v8.9.1

watchman 4.9.0
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[Please have a look here for help with troubleshooting](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/7308)

I would suggest you try all the solutions described in that thread to try and fix this issue. Good Luck!